# If function not exist then create function in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, functions, syntax

```
    If not  Exists (Select * from sys.objects where name ='FNLX_getDate'  and type =N'FN')

    Create function [dbo].[FNLX_getDate]() returns Datetime
    as
    Begin
    .................
    End
```

When I execute the above script I get the error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'function'.

What can be wrong?

Using Microsoft SQL Server to execute above script.

Comment: Why did this get closed as off-topic? It helped me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running SQL Server 2016 SP1+, you can use `CREATE OR ALTER` to avoid conditionally dropping the function beforehand:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FNLX_getDate]() returns Datetime
AS
BEGIN
...
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't use `create function` like that. It must be the first statement in a batch.

You can try dynamic SQL instead like:

```
If not Exists (Select * from sys.objects where name ='FNLX_getDate'  and type =N'FN')
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
        SET @sql = N'CREATE FUNCTION ...';
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    END
```

Or the classic way (like you can see if you generate scripts with SSMS) : drop and create:

```
If Exists (Select * from sys.objects where name ='FNLX_getDate'  and type =N'FN')
    drop function [dbo].[FNLX_getDate]
GO
Create function [dbo].[FNLX_getDate]() returns Datetime
as
Begin
.................
End
```

Notice the `GO` SSMS batch separator.

Comment: i used dynamic sql but in function i have line Return cast('Timezone conversion: Database timezone should be same as Application timezone or UTC in LU_TimeZoneConfig Table ' as int); when i execute  its showing error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
Incorrect syntax near 'Timezone '.

Comment: @NikhilD You need to [have two single quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560) when building dynamic SQL. For example `EXEC('SELECT [MyStringValue] = ''asdf''')` Note there are two `'` not one `"` before `asdf` and three of them after.